Algorithm to filter the address from a large text
I am trying to grab part of this string, I am looking for it to start grabbing the string at the first digit in the string and copy the entire string all the away until the end digits.
import re

string = "['Today is the open house of 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204; open to the Public "

property_address = re.findall('\d-\d\d\d\d\d', str(string))

print(property_address)

Code above does not work, I'm a bit confused on how to tell Regex, start on first digit you find and grab until you find 5 digit sequence.

Use [1-9].*[1-9][0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})? or [1-9].*[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?

Please go through an actual tutorial of regex first, and you'll find .* to match any characters (that is by default not a newline) of any length.

@blhsing, agreed and sorry, I literally had just gotten into the "Qualifiers" section and stopped took the lazy road, I searched the first instance of the documentation for ".*" and it was just below where I was. I am going to try the answer above and then try to make sense why if that works.

You mean "quantifiers". And yes, if you simply finish the quantifiers section you should be able to answer this question.

You can use:
import re

s = """
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204 - 1829
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf  1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 00204 - 1829
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, 3rd, 4th phone number 1391713917 Denver, COLORADO 00204 - 1829 aldfjald

"""

p = r'\b[1-9].*[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)?'

find_address = re.findall(p, s)

print(find_address)


Prints

['1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204', '1234 High Drive, Denver,
COLORADO 80204', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 00204', '1234 High
Drive, 3rd, 4th phone number 1391713917 Denver, COLORADO 00204']

Notes

Occasionally, there is a - and four digits after zipcode. Right? That should be considered.

\b[1-9].*[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)?:

\b is a word boundary.
[1-9] assumes that the address starts with [1-9] numbers and not 0. If you want 0, then use \b[0-9].*[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)?.
(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)? is an optional group. It means, if the group is in the text, will take it, otherwise no.
[0-9]{5} means all digits, only five times.


Edge cases

Just in case, if we had multiple addresses in one input, then we use the lazy matching as opposed to greedy.

\b[1-9].*?[0-9]{5}\b(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)?
Code
import re

s = """ aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf  1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, 3rd, 4th phone numbers (391) 871-3912 1-391-871-3912 Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829 aldfjald

aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204 - 1829aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 

"""

p = r'\b[1-9].*?[0-9]{5}\b(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)?'

find_address = re.findall(p, s)

print(find_address)



Prints

['1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204', '1234 High Drive, Denver,
COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829',
'1234 High Drive, 3rd, 4th phone numbers (391) 871-3912 1-391-871-3912
Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO
80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234
High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver,
COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204',
'1829aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO
80204-1829']


Algorithms

If you need 100% accuracy, it's best to write algorithms to solve this problem. Then, continuously improve your algorithms to deal with any edge cases.

Otherwise, fixing one or multiple regex would be tedious. Note that you can also use regex in your algorithms, if you want.




For example, you can create some "known" sets. e.g., check and see if there is a state/country and that is in the state/country set. You might be able to even do this for cities/zip-codes.

Similarly, for written numbers or other special words in the addres (One, Two, Three etc.), you can use sets.

Address usually has a limited length. Maybe 50-100 chars? Right? You can use this info in your algorithms.

Address does not have certain chars (e.g., %, $, *, etc.) and you can use it to test against those.

Addresses have similar and common chars/words (e.g., South, S., North, N., West, W., Avenue, AVE, Ave., Street, St., BLVD, Boulevard, Blvd., Suite, STE, Apt., Apartment, etc.). You can use these substrings in a set, and check and see if any of them are in a possible address string. This will increases the probability of that string being an address.

The list goes on and on....



Algorithm is a better choice, it is easier to understand and maintain.
Example Algorithm:

import re

s = """aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf  1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf
aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, 3rd, 4th phone numbers (391) 871-3912 1-391-871-3912 Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829 aldfjald

aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf 1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829 aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf aldjfladjfa alsdjflaksjdf

wer and Lender covenant and agree as follows:1. Property in Trust. Borrower, in consideration of the indebtedness herein recited and the trust herein created, her - 6620 FAWN PATH LANE, CASTLE PINES, COLORADO 80108
and the Public Trustee of the County in whichthe Property(see § 1) is situated(Trustee)
for the benefit of THE EDILEEN M. BIRNBAUM _TESTAMENTARY TRUST(Lender), whose address is 3617 SPRINGBROOK STREET, DALLAS, TEXAS 75205.Borrower and Lender covenant and agree as follows:
    1. Property in Trust. Borrower, in consideration of the indebtedness herein recited and the trust herein created, her -
"""

states = {
    'AL': 'Alabama',
    'AK': 'Alaska',
    'AZ': 'Arizona',
    'AR': 'Arkansas',
    'CA': 'California',
    'CO': 'Colorado',
    'CT': 'Connecticut',
    'DE': 'Delaware',
    'FL': 'Florida',
    'GA': 'Georgia',
    'HI': 'Hawaii',
    'ID': 'Idaho',
    'IL': 'Illinois',
    'IN': 'Indiana',
    'IA': 'Iowa',
    'KS': 'Kansas',
    'KY': 'Kentucky',
    'LA': 'Louisiana',
    'ME': 'Maine',
    'MD': 'Maryland',
    'MA': 'Massachusetts',
    'MI': 'Michigan',
    'MN': 'Minnesota',
    'MS': 'Mississippi',
    'MO': 'Missouri',
    'MT': 'Montana',
    'NE': 'Nebraska',
    'NV': 'Nevada',
    'NH': 'New Hampshire',
    'NJ': 'New Jersey',
    'NM': 'New Mexico',
    'NY': 'New York',
    'NC': 'North Carolina',
    'ND': 'North Dakota',
    'OH': 'Ohio',
    'OK': 'Oklahoma',
    'OR': 'Oregon',
    'PA': 'Pennsylvania',
    'RI': 'Rhode Island',
    'SC': 'South Carolina',
    'SD': 'South Dakota',
    'TN': 'Tennessee',
    'TX': 'Texas',
    'UT': 'Utah',
    'VT': 'Vermont',
    'VA': 'Virginia',
    'WA': 'Washington',
    'WV': 'West Virginia',
    'WI': 'Wisconsin',
    'WY': 'Wyoming'
}

patterns = r'\b[1-9].*?[0-9]{5}\b(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)?'


def get_possible_addreses(s):
    possible_addresses = re.findall(patterns, s)
    return possible_addresses


def get_states():
    states_in_address = []
    for k, v in states.items():
        states_in_address += [k.lower(), v.lower()]
    return states_in_address


def may_be_an_address(s, size=50):
    words = s.split()[::-1]
    check_words = []
    numbers = []
    is_state = []
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in get_states():
            is_state += [word]
        if word.isdigit():
            numbers += [int(word)]
        check_words += [word]
        size -= len(word)
        if len(numbers) >= 2 and size <= 0:
            break
        if size <= 0 and len(numbers) < 2:
            size += 5
    possible_address = ' '.join(check_words[::-1]) if is_state else None

    return possible_address if re.match("^" + patterns + "$", possible_address) else None


res = []

for s in get_possible_addreses(s):
    possible_address = may_be_an_address(s, 50)
    if possible_address is not None:
        res += [possible_address]
print(res)


Prints

['1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204', '1234 High Drive, Denver,
COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829',
'1234 High Drive, 3rd, 4th phone numbers (391) 871-3912 1-391-871-3912
Denver, COLORADO 00204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO
80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234
High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver,
COLORADO 80204-1829', '1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829',
'1234 High Drive, Denver, COLORADO 80204-1829', '3617 SPRINGBROOK
STREET, DALLAS, TEXAS 75205']

Note that regex is just a set of algorithms, can be written in a shorter form.

The above algorithm "works", but is not complete (e.g., modify it for multiple words states such as New Mexico or countries, if any). You need to add more methods and modify some methods. My point is that, it is better to stay away from regex, as much as possible, for these type of problems.

Note that, I intentionally wrote the regex "pretty loose" and did not add too much complexity in it.



Thanks much! I was about to ask what was up with the "(?:-[0-9]{4}\b)" but that makes sense with the additional 4 for the zip.

Is there anything within the text string that could prevent this from working? I am finding when using a large string that it is not working. BUT if I remove part of the string at the end and shorten it down, it does work? I have removed any extra lines thinking that may be the issue, I'm a bit perplexed. Working on getting this string copied somewhere so you can take a look at it.

"""['6620 FAWN PATH LANE, CASTLE PINES, COLORADO 80108; and the Public Trustee of the County in whichthe Property (see § 1) is situated (Trustee); for the benefit of THE EDILEEN M. BIRNBAUM _TESTAMENTARY TRUST(Lender), whose address is 3617 SPRINGBROOK STREET, DALLAS, TEXAS 75205.Borrower and Lender covenant and agree as follows:1. Property in Trust. Borrower, in consideration of the indebtedness herein recited and the trust herein created, her""" -- Can you try this string? I am super confused on this one. It seems to give all the way until the TX address, but it should have stopped at 80108?

This will obviously also fail on addresses which don't have a street number, or have it spelled out as a word, like One Microsoft Way or Sleepy Hollow.

The greedy wildcard .* matches the longest possible string. As a crutch, you can change it to a non-greedy .*?; demo: https://ideone.com/YjKQ9t ... but that will still straddle numbers; change . "any character" to \D "any non-digit character" to change that (and add \d* after the first \b[1-9] to permit multiple digits) https://ideone.com/nCdpBI

@josh Updated. The best way is to write algorithm and fix for your edge cases, as you go. This seems to be for legal documents. In that case, the format should not look like so bad.

@Josh This algorithm is not fully complete. Wrote it quickly. You need to add and modify more functions. My point is that, it is better to stay away from regex, as much as possible, for these type of problems. Note that, I intentionally wrote the regex "pretty loose" and did not add too much complexity in it.
